# Is it typical for supervisors to never explain to subordinates?

Tags: management

I am new to a job. When my supervisor ask me to do a certain task that I feel a bit unreasonable. I often ask why & try not to offend him. My supervisor doesn't explain and ask me just do it. He never explain to me anything.

I know I am young & new. So I am trying to figure out if this is a typical behavior of supervisors & I should do anything without questions

Comment: Maybe your supervisor feels that you should already understand why these tasks must be done?

Comment: Try leading into a question with "what" instead of "why". There's plenty of psychology that shows that "why" can put people on edge. You're explicitly inquiring into their reasoning and often times this comes off as doubt or questioning their authority and judgement. As he _is_ your supervisor, don't piss him off. The next time he gives you a task, consider saying, "Sure thing boss, what's the goal here?" You're confirming that you've heard his request while adhering to it and you're simply asking that you want to know the objective.

Comment: Typical? No. Common? Yes.

Comment: The "why" is above your pay grade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is very industry-specific. If you work in a restaurant kitchen, and the boss tells you to "take everything out of that fridge and put it into that other fridge" you say "yes chef" or "yes sir" as appropriate. You don't stop and have a chit chat about the motivations for the switch or whether you're the best person to do it. If you're on a construction site and the boss says "use that wheelbarrow to take these bags of [whatever] over there and pile them neatly" you again say "yes sir" rather than asking why the bags need to be there or whether a mechanized solution exists to the problem of moving the bags. If you work in a retail store and just spend 3 hours folding sweaters and the boss says "clear off that table and box up the sweaters in the back room" you again say "yes sir" not "I think it's cold out today and people will want to buy sweaters."

In a typical office job, programming or administration or architecture or engineering, there's more of an expectation that you can ask questions so that you understand what is being asked of you. If the boss isn't as technical as you, it's possible your suggestions will be useful, so your questions are not just for clarification but perhaps an opportunity to challenge your instructions and change your tasks on occasion. **This is not the same as the boss owing you an explanation for the task you've been assigned.** You may feel something is unreasonable because of how little you know, or because it's unreasonable. Sometimes, it really is unreasonable and you really do have to do it - maybe a customer has changed their mind and the powers that be have told your boss this has to be done and that's that. You pointing out it's unreasonable isn't helping anyone.

Ideally, your boss would share information with you and give you the guidance you need to feel comfortable in your job. And your boss would also listen to you if you think you know a better way to do something. In most office workplaces this is the norm. In others, it's the norm after a certain period of time working together, when the boss knows what you know. And in still others, it never happens because the boss is thinking more like the chef or the construction foreman and expects plenty of "yes sir" from you. I suggest you say 'yes sir" for a while and observe how the boss is with others. If nobody ever gets the kind of back-and-forth that you want in this job, then when you look for your next job, you'll know one of the things you're looking for. But if others do seem to have more input, you know what you are working towards in this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask others around you - perhaps they have a better idea of what is required. Typically a supervisor does not do the job so one of you colleagues would be able to help

Comment: yes, i tried. the problem is my colleagues also dont know why they are doing it. he never explain to anyone. and ppl are afraid to ask

Comment: @kaboom That's *not* normal, but sadly not unheard of either.

Comment: @kaboom - you work at a place where nobody knows why they are doing anything?

Comment: @WorkerDrone That actually can make sense in some situations (but without the "being afraid" part). I know of a (at least one) tech R&D site where most people are not told how their work contributes to the big picture, nobody gets tasks for the same thing a second time (ie. everything is being shuffled around to prevent a person learning too much about a product/model/type), etc.etc. . Reason is to prevent competition to steal their inventions.

Comment: @deviantfan - sure. And most workers on the Manhattan Project didn't know what their efforts would build. It's hard to know what's really going on at kaboom's company without a lot more details.

Comment: @WorkerDrone Hopefully "kaboom" is a coincidence :/

Comment: @deviantfan - LOL!

Answer (score 1):

No. The only time this is typical is when the supervisor doesn't know how to do it. Sometimes you have non tech or incompetent supervisors and they can do this quite a bit.

Typical is the supervisor at least running you through procedures unless it is something you are supposed to be qualified for already, but even then it's normal to run you through at least once, since different places have different procedures.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal in some places, and it's stupid. It either happens because the supervisor is so full of himself or herself that he doesn't see you as a human being who deserves some explanation, or because the supervisor himself or herself is clueless and has no ideas why they are telling you to do something.

Either way I'd say that supervisor doesn't have a great career ahead of them because he or she is entirely demotivating to the people working for him or her, which means his team will always be less efficient then teams with a better supervisor. So with a bit of effort you should be able to pass him on your way up easily.

Answer (score 0):

Your supervisor's personal management style is just that - personal. You will find different managers interact with their subordinates in different ways. Your current supervisor's top-down "just get it done" way of handing things is only one facet of the spectrum.

There are [6 "classical" management](http://www.fastcompany.com/1838481/6-leadership-styles-and-when-you-should-use-them) styles and plenty of other flavors like "management by walking around". That isn't to say your supervisor cleanly fits in to any of these styles; most of us are a combination, and most of us use different styles for different situations.

Of course, dealing with people is never as easy as sorting them into a management style, but maybe this will help you understand what could be motivating your supervisor in how he does his job.